# Packer | Ansible | NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, packer, amazon-efs

I am trying to execute ansible script via Packer to Obtain EFS facts. Within my packer.json I am passing AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/KEY/TOKEN. My facts.yml works fine if I execute it individually by passing `-sts_assume_role` in my code.

As suggested by @error404 I have added sts_assume_role task and received updated logs to the question.

tasks/facts.yml:

```
# Get all RDS instances
---

- sts_assume_role:
    region: "central"
    role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::12345678919:role/jenkins"
    role_session_name: "ansible-connect"
  register: assumed_role

- name: Obtain all EFS facts
  efs_facts:
    aws_access_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.secret_key }}"
    security_token: "{{ assumed_role.sts_creds.session_token }}"
    region: "eu-central-1"
  register: airflow_efs_facts

- debug:
    var: airflow_efs_facts.ansible_facts.efs[0].filesystem_address
```

my packer.json

```
{
  "variables": {
    "aws_region": "eu-central-1",
    "kms_key_id": "{{env `KEY`}}",
    "aws_access_key": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
    "aws_secret_key": "{{env `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
    "aws_session_token": "{{env `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`}}",
    "subnet_id": "{{env `SUBNET`}}",
    "vpc_id": "{{env `VPC`}}"
  },
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "access_key": "{{user `aws_access_key`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `aws_secret_key`}}",
      "token": "{{user `aws_session_token`}}",
      "region": "{{user `aws_region`}}",
      "vpc_id": "{{user `vpc_id`}}",
      "subnet_id": "{{user `subnet_id`}}",

      "source_ami_filter": {
        "filters": {
            "name": "ec2-*",
            "virtualization-type": "hvm",
            "root-device-type": "ebs"
        },
        "owners": "self",
        "most_recent": true
      },
      "encrypt_boot": "true",
      "kms_key_id": "{{user `kms_key_id`}}",
      "instance_type": "t2.large",
      "ssh_username": "ec2-user",
      "ami_block_device_mappings": [
        {
          "device_name": "/dev/xvda",
          "volume_size": 20,
          "volume_type": "gp2",
          "delete_on_termination": true
        }
      ],
      "launch_block_device_mappings": [
         {
            "device_name": "/dev/xvda",
            "volume_size": 20,
            "volume_type": "gp2",
            "delete_on_termination": true
         }
    ],
      "ami_description": "Master AMI to be used to build Server",
      "ami_name": "master-{{isotime \"2006-01-02\"}}",
      "tags": {
        "Name": "master-baseline",
        "ami_version": "{{isotime \"2006-01-02\"}}",
        "ami_cis_benchmark_version": "1.0.0",
        "ami_os": "amazon"
      }
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
    {
      "inline": [
        "sudo yum -y install bzip2 python-pip vim wget curl mlocate unzip git  java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel java-1.8.0-openjdk jq",
        "sudo updatedb",
        "sudo pip install ansible",
        "sudo yum -y install python3 python3-pip python3-devel python3-setuptools",
        "sudo yum -y update"
      ],
      "type": "shell"
    },
    {
      "type": "ansible-local",
      "playbook_file": "ansible/plays/install.yml",
      "role_paths": [
            "ansible/roles/master"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Below is the error message:**

> [0;32m    amazon-ebs: TASK [roles/airflow-master : sts_assume_role]
> **********************************[0m [0;32m    amazon-ebs: [0;31mAn exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback,
> use -vvv. The error was: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError:
> Unable to locate credentials[0m[0m [0;32m    amazon-ebs: [0;31mfatal:
> [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback
> (most recent call last):\n  File
> "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1560349713.84-28986519228608/AnsiballZ_sts_assume_role.py",
> line 114, in \n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File
> "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1560349713.84-28986519228608/AnsiballZ_sts_assume_role.py",
> line 106, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path,
> ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File
> "/home/ec2-user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1560349713.84-28986519228608/AnsiballZ_sts_assume_role.py",
> line 49, in invoke_module\n

Comment: the playbook needs aws credentials for executing the tasks. the error is expected I believe the access creds defined under the vars section is used by packer to perform the building operations. Since you are trying to execute ansible in provisioned you need to provide the creds file or some authentication

Comment: @error404 I have updated my ansible script along with new error.

Comment: the error still remains the same the ansible play inside the virtual machine should have access to AWS.

Comment: @error404 How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided by Rickard von Essen?

Answer (score 0):

> Within my `packer.json` I am passing AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID/KEY/TOKEN

You are just setting these as Packer *user variables*. This only means that packer can access them in the template with `` {{user `aws_access_key`}} ``.

A good way to solve this is to create an [EC2 Instance Profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) which is authorised to access the EFS api and reference it with [iam_instance_profile](https://packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html#iam_instance_profile).